# Specify source branch in addition to target branch in PR workflow trigger?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to be able to specify a specific `source`-`target` combination to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow, rather than just a `target` branch. How might I do this?

Here's the idea (this doesn't actually work):

```yaml
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      target_branch: "main"
      source_branch: "dev"
```

My use case for this is a pre-prod check that runs on PRs into `main`. I want the pattern to be that folks need to get their changes into the semi-protected `dev` branch first, rather than opening the PR into `main` from their own unvetted feature branches. Then, only `dev` sourced PRs are allowed to trigger the pre-prod check.

I know I could get similar functionality by combining a PR trigger with an Environment Protection rule, but I'm not actually trying to limit deployments from certain branches broadly (I have a `dev` process that some users should be able to trigger at will) but rather be able to granularly specify which `source`-`target` combinations trigger specific workflows when PRs are opened/updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own answer in the docs: [Running your pull_request workflow based on the head or base branch of a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request_target-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request)

You can set jobs to only run if the source/HEAD branch matches a certain name pattern. When coupled with the on `pull_request` branch trigger:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"] # the target branch

jobs:
  job_that_only_runs_when_head_ref_is_dev:
    if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'dev' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "This job run came from branch 'dev'!"
```